# Android and JFileChooser

Tags: java, android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, jfilechooser, android-2.3-gingerbread

I've developed a desktop application that allows the user to extract images from their phone.

When I first started this project, my android was running Gingerbread. When I plugged my phone into the laptop via USB, it would appear as a  "Device with removable storage". Therefore, the JFileChooser would pick it up.

```
nwdir = new JFileChooser();
            nwdir.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("C:\\"));
            nwdir.setDialogTitle(choosertitle);
            nwdir.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
            nwdir.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(true);
```

However, I recently upgraded the phone's o/s to Icecream and it now shows up on the desktop as a "portable device". This is something that the JFileChooser cannot see?!

Has anyone got any suggestions on how to get around this problem? I was going to roll back the O/S of the phone, but this somewhat limits the application's device support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default transfer mode has been changed in Android 4.0 Ice Cream Sandwich from USB Mass Storage mode to MTP (Media Transfer Protocol) which doesn't use a standard filesystem mount. On some phones it is possible to [change the USB mode](http://www.jayceooi.com/2012/03/14/how-to-enable-usb-mass-storage-on-android-4-0-ics-samsung-galaxy-s2/) while on others it may be necessary to [install an apk to enable it](http://knowmydroid.com/blog/enable-usb-mass-storage-mode-in-ice-cream-sandwich)

Comment: dmi_, Thanks for your reply. I've found a way around it by doing this....
Settings > Wireless & Network > USB utilities and click the button > then (and ONLY then) plug in USB cable

Answer (score 1):

I've found a way around it by doing this.... Settings > Wireless & Network > USB utilities and click the button > then (and ONLY then) plug in USB cable