# Filter file extensions for a simple file manager

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a simple file manager. In the directory while i am browsing for files it will only show some specific file extensions such as only .txt and .pdf . It will also show the directories. How can i do it. What should be added or modify of the following code. FileManager.java file is-

```
package com.radiobot.speedreaderv1_1;


import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;



import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class FileManager extends ListActivity {

        private enum DISPLAYMODE{ ABSOLUTE, RELATIVE; }

        private final DISPLAYMODE displayMode = DISPLAYMODE.ABSOLUTE;
        private List<String> directoryEntries = new ArrayList<String>();
        private File currentDirectory = new File("/");

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
                super.onCreate(icicle);
                browseToRoot();
        }


        private void browseToRoot() {
                browseTo(new File("/"));
    }


        private void upOneLevel(){
                if(this.currentDirectory.getParent() != null)
                        this.browseTo(this.currentDirectory.getParentFile());
        }

        private void browseTo(final File aDirectory){
                if (aDirectory.isDirectory()){
                        this.currentDirectory = aDirectory;
                        fill(aDirectory.listFiles());
                }
                    else{
                        OnClickListener okButtonListener = new OnClickListener(){
                                // @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                                        {


                                            try
                                            {
                                            Intent myIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

                                            File file = new File(aDirectory.getAbsolutePath());
                                            String extension = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(Uri.fromFile(file).toString());

                                            String mimetype = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
                                            myIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),mimetype);
                                            startActivity(myIntent);
                                            }
                                            catch (Exception e)
                                            {
                                            e.getMessage();
                                            }

                                        }
                                }
                        };
                        OnClickListener cancelButtonListener = new OnClickListener(){
                                // @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                                        // Do nothing
                                }
                        };

                        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                        .setTitle(
                                "Do you want to open this file" + aDirectory.getName())
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", okButtonListener)
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", cancelButtonListener)
                                                                .show();
                }
        }

        private void fill(File[] files) {
                this.directoryEntries.clear();

                try {
                        Thread.sleep(10);
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                this.directoryEntries.add("");

                if(this.currentDirectory.getParent() != null)
                        this.directoryEntries.add("..");

                switch(this.displayMode){
                        case ABSOLUTE:
                                for (File file : files){
                                        this.directoryEntries.add(file.getPath());
                                }
                                break;
                        case RELATIVE:
                                int currentPathStringLenght = this.currentDirectory.getAbsolutePath().length();
                                for (File file : files){
                                        this.directoryEntries.add(file.getAbsolutePath().substring(currentPathStringLenght));
                                }
                                break;
                }

                ArrayAdapter<String> directoryList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                                R.layout.filemanager, this.directoryEntries);

                this.setListAdapter(directoryList);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

            String position2 = (String) l.getItemAtPosition(position);

        String selectedFileString = position2;

                if (selectedFileString.equals(".")) {
                        // Refresh
                        this.browseTo(this.currentDirectory);
                } else if(selectedFileString.equals("..")){
                        this.upOneLevel();
                } else {
                        File clickedFile = null;
                        switch(this.displayMode){
                                case RELATIVE:

                                    clickedFile = new File(position2);
                                        break;
                                case ABSOLUTE:

                                    clickedFile = new File(position2);    
                                    break;
                        }
                        if(clickedFile != null)

                                this.browseTo(clickedFile);
                }
        }


}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853611/how-can-i-add-sdcard-images-to-coverflow/15853710#15853710 check this might help. filtering files that end with.png you can use | operator to match txt| pdf..

Answer (score 0):

[This may be useful.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileNameExtensionFilter.html)

> FileFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("JPEG file", "jpg",
>   "jpeg");  JFileChooser fileChooser = ...; 
>   fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);

Comment: this is android. JFileChoosr is for java i guess

Comment: Would you please tell me that where should i put the above code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934099/android-and-jfilechooser ... I'm pretty sure it can be used. I don't want to go out of my scope of knowledge and say something I don't know. I apologize for coming here somewhat misinformed, but I'll leave them here as relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

In `browseTo()` you add all the files in the directory to the list:

```
fill(aDirectory.listFiles()); // here's the problem
```

Take a look at [`File.listFiles(FileFilter filter)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28java.io.FileFilter%29), this returns only the files that conform to the specified filter.

```
File[] files = aDirectory.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
    @Override
    boolean accept(File pathname) {
        // return true if and only if pathname has the desired extension
        if (pathname.getName().endsWith(".txt") || pathname.isDirectory())
            return true; // accept only .txt files and directories
        else
            return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: What should be replaced by pathname? how should i write that?

Comment: In the accept method, you write your logic by processing the pathname, and return true or false.

Comment: i have added 
                        
                        File[] files = aDirectory.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
                            @Override
       public
                            boolean accept(File pathname) {
                               
                                if (pathname.getName().endsWith(".txt"))
                                    return true;
                                else
                                    return false;
                            }
                        });
but its not working. its showing all the files.

Comment: I have uploaded the project to http://tinyurl.com/speedreaderv1 . would u please download and solve it for me ? thanks

Comment: You know, that's not how this site works. You have every info you need right on this page, just use it.

Comment: yes i know. But as i am very beginner so if you please help me i will be greatfull.

Comment: Okay... What exactly don't you understand? Replace the first block of code from my answer with the second. That's it.

Comment: yes i did, but its not showing any file. its showing and empty page.

Comment: Do you have any `.txt` files in that directory? You probably don't.

Comment: I have. On the other hand I need to show the directories to that folder also.