# Selecting external device with DirectoryChooser

Tags: java, javafx, external, filechooser

Is there a way of making external devices appear on the JavaFx DirectoryChooser's dialog box?
If not, are there any alternatives?

What I need to do is copy/paste files from a pc to a directory in a android phone's sdcard through a java application. 
Since I'm using javaFx I tried selecting the destination folder with a DirectoryChooser but it doesn't appear to detect the device.

Answer (score 2):

As I know, the phone should be set to USB storage rather than MTP (Media Transfer Protocol) to be able to locate it with JavaFX File/DirectoryBrowser. (That means e.g. on Windows that the drive letter appears).

The same problem occurs with Swing JFileChooser: [Android and JFileChooser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934099/android-and-jfilechooser)

Also the documentation of [DirectoryChooser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/DirectoryChooser.html) of JavaFX states:

> On some platforms where file access may be restricted or not part of
>   the user model (for example, on some mobile or embedded devices),
>   opening a directory dialog may always result in a no-op (that is, null
>   file being returned).